# Find my computer's MAC address with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireless, lan, mac-address

Using the function I found from a forum/thread(listed below), I can find the MAC address of my computer in python. However, this function returns the wrong MAC address. This computer has an ethernet and Wireless lan adapter. The computer I am using uses the Wireless LAN adapter. How do I find what MAC the computer is using and what the the Physical Address(MAC) of that adapter is?

This is the code I found that returns the incorrect MAC:

```
def get_mac():
    import uuid
    return str(':'.join(['{:02x}'.format((uuid.getnode() >> i) & 0xff) for i in range(0,8*6,8)][::-1])).upper()
```

If any more information is necessary, please post a comment and I will add what I can

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux you can find the list of adapters here:
*/sys/class/net/*

And read the MAC address of a specific interface, for example *eth0*, like this:

```
with open('/sys/class/net/eth0/address') as f:
    mac = f.read()
```

Comment: Does not  work for every system, some do not have `sys` virtual filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
```

**Note:** Please consdier  may be it return octet or decimal and you watch hex in output of `ifconfig`

Comment: Right now I am using the exact same thing. The code I am using uses uuid.getnode() and adds colons every 2 characters

Comment: Did you check for octet or decimal , Also check for all of interfaces, use `ifconfig -a`

Comment: I am using Windows. ipconfig /all shows me my MAC address. But how do I use this in python

Comment: >>> import os
>>> os.system("ipconfig /all")

Comment: How do I search through to find my MAC though? Would I have to use regex?

Comment: except regex, you don't have any solution, But if i prefer to use previous solution not call other application.

Comment: MAC of what network interface does it provide? The value I receive of that does not comply to any of realy existing in my system.